# enhance the wordpress security to access directly folder

Tags: php, wordpress, security

once i upload the new image to wordpress the `new directory` will be created once the month change `(like in aug /var/www/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2015/08)`. which not contains the index.php file so every one who know the wordpress directory structure can directly access that folder. so what i want to do is create a `index.php` file once the new upload directory created. so i can put the better security to `wordpress`. your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Disable Directory Indexing using .htaccess

Create new file `.htaccess` in `/var/www/mysite/wp-content/`

or

Add the following line to your exiting `.htaccess` file.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: if i do this then will not open my site

Comment: @bhaveshvala the above solution does not effect your site. It simply disable directory listing only.

Comment: will you please explain how can i do it i have not fully server access.?

Comment: @bhaveshvala you just need ftp access for it. In your folder `/var/www/mysite/` there must be file by name `.htaccess`. Just download this file and Add `Options -Indexes` to your exiting .htaccess file.

Comment: @bhaveshvala I'm glad it work for you. Its simple and quick solution :)

Answer (score 3):

i have faced such kind of issues previously and i have used the wordpress filter `upload_dir` to fixed it.

please add this code to you `function.php` file and upload image in your media.

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'sofg_secure_dir');
function sofg_secure_dir( $param ){ 
   $filename = $param['path'].'/index.php';
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = "<?php // silence is golden  ?>";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
    }
    return $param; 
}
```

Comment: upload any image from media so my upload filter will be executes and create index.php file..